# PHP: Assign $page variable if page url is = to '?'

Tags: php, variables

Is there a way in PHP to assign or display a variable if the page URL is equal to a specific value?

I have a site with 100 pages. Each page has a list of variables that are echoed through it based on `$page` variable. I would like to have this variable assigned on the fly. I want to be able to set a variable, 1-100 for example, based on page URL.

If page URL is equal to

> www.example.com/page/dog

set the `$page` variable for page to `dog`.

If page URL is equal to

> www.example.com/page/cat

set the `$page` variable for page to `cat`.

So on and so forth. Once the variable is set certain things will happen. In order for the correct information to be displayed I need the correct page variable to be set.

Below is ALL the code that exists on each page.

```
<?php $page = 'example1'; ?> 
<?php include '../includes/core/overall/header.php'; ?>
<?php include '../includes/core/overall/footer.php'; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])` like this:

```
<?php

include '../includes/core/overall/header.php'; 
include '../includes/core/overall/footer.php'; 

$var = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']); 
//get page with .php

$var = preg_replace('/\.php$/', '', $var); 
//remove .php from end

if($var == "dog"){
    $page = "dog";
}
else if($var == "cat"){
    $page = "cat";
}
else{
    $page = "foo";
}
echo $page;
?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This would work but I would have to write out over 100 if statements on each and every page as there are over 100 pages. Can the last word in the url after the '/' and before the '.php' be put into the page variable with out doing if statements? I already have another file with 100 conditionals in it. If $page is equal to '?' display these variables else. Need to put the url (or last part of url) straight into the variable.

Comment: Sure, that's possible.  If you're just trying to display the page title in the `<head>` section, then simply `echo $var;`. You don't need the `if` statements for that.

Comment: Ok it's working. Sorta. I need to adjust my code a bit and see if i can get it to work.

Comment: @user2526699: feel free to vote up and accept the answer if you find it useful :)

Comment: Ok I was able to echo it so that I could see it. so now $var is = to my url. How do I take the value of $var and put it in $page?

Comment: $page = $var  I also had to place the includes below it. Got it to work tho. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

```
$page = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of HTTP's pathinfo.

#### $DOCUMENT_ROOT/page/index.php:

```
<?
  $page = substr($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], 1);
   ...
```

Comment: I'm still fresh to php I apologize. How would I write the above code into my page? I have edited my question to include ALL of the code on each page.

Comment: I'm assuming just as you have typed it.

Comment: In the file that I have named.

Comment: I am trying to run it but getting Undefined index: PATH_INFO. I'm trying to set the variable. As I am on a local machine running from local host is there another script i can run to show me the value of the above script to set my varible with?

Comment: Calling `phpinfo()` will show you everything about your PHP setup, but it may be that pathinfo is disabled on your server. Which web server software are you using?